How to operate with complex coefficients in patsy and is it possible?
I tried to construct dmatrix from the dataframe of dtype='complex', but I got the error:
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'multiply' output from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
Can I operate with complex dataframes with patsy or is there some convenient alternative?
